# Apache2 + Tomcat static resources

Tags: tomcat, apache2, reverse-proxy

I set an Apache2 as a reverse proxy for a Tomcat. My server.xml in Tomcat has the next AJP config:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

And Apache config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLProxyEngine On
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /home/xxxxxx/store/f******.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/xxxxxx/p*******.pem
    # Servers to proxy the connection, or
    # List of application servers Usage
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/x/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/x/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

My web app is using Spring Security. 
Currently the Apache is serving pages (jsp) fine, but no static resources. Is impossible to reach any resource. 
If I put in a browser

https://example.com/x/resources/img/logo.jpg

I can't see the logo. But if I put

https://example.com:8443/x/resources/img/logo.jpg

it appears.

Any help will be very welcomed.

Thanks in advance guys ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not mapping the URL the way you want.  You have:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/x/
```

That means that the `/x` portion is already in the URL and is hidden from outside of Apache.  So if you want `/x/resources/img/logo.jpg` from Tomcat then the URL will be `http://hostname.tld/resources/img/logo.jpg` outside of Apache.

If you want to maintain the `/x` in the path then change your mapping to be

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

so that the `/x` will be passed through.

**EDIT**

In the interest of clarity and to prevent a ton of comments I'll layout the four basic ways to use Apache in front of Tomcat.

1 - Pure pass through.  In this case your Apache configuration looks like `ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/` (or `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/` for an HTTP proxy).  The Tomcat instance gets the exact same URL that Apache gets.  I've used this to let Apache be the SSL endpoint as it's easier and better documented on how to setup SSL on Apache.  Usually in this case there is only one Tomcat virtual host.

2 - URL rewrite (sort of).  This is what you're looking at now.  Apache config looks like `ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/appName/`.  This allows you to "hide" the `appName` portion of the URL.  So if an external user requests `http://hostname.tld/blah.jpg` the URL that is sent to Tomcat is `/appName/blah.jpg`  The only challenge with this setup is that code on the Tomcat side that generates a link (i.e. an HTML anchor tag) needs to be aware to not generate a URL that includes the `/appName` in it.  In this case there can be multiple Tomcat virtual hosts that may be in parallel to Apache virtual hosts.

3 - Apache serves static resources.  In this case your mapping in Apache is something like `ProxyPass /dynamic ajp://localhost:8009/appName/`.  You'd request Tomcat resources at something like  `http://hostname.tld/dynamic/index.jsp`.  You'd move your static resources to somewhere Apache can access them and handle that with a prefix on the URL like `http://hostname.tld/static/picture.jpg`  This can be via rewrite rules or other Apache configurations.

4 - Forget Apache.  Run Tomcat as a user that can bind to port 80 (root on Unix-like environments) and just serve everything from Tomcat.  SSL is a bit of a pain to setup but it can be done and the webapp context (i.e. `/x` in your case) can be eliminated in a few ways, the simplest being placing your content in ROOT for Tomcat.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Hi, stdunbar, thanks for your answer. My app is running in /x. So, as far as I know, to be able to access the app from example.com I have to put / in Apache2 and /x in Tomcat. Any case I gave a try to your suggestion but it doesn't work. Now I am suspecting something. Being normally Apache is used to serve static resources, perhaps this is the standard behaviour? I mean, perhaps I have to configure Apache2 to serve the static resources and let the dynamic pages to Tomcat. What do you think?

Comment: You *can* let Apache serve the static resources but you don't have to.  If you do then you'd have to move things like `/resources` to somewhere that Tomcat won't serve them.  But if you want to "hide" the `/x` then you just need to change the URL that the outside world uses as I indicated.  I guess the question is do you want the `/x` in the URL or not?

Comment: Obviously to add /x to my domain name is not an option. So I guess the way you are suggesting imply to move my app to ROOT in Tomcat. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you very much, stdunbar, move my application to ROOT did the trick. In any case, I still do not understand why in / x route, pages were served, but static resources do not, they appeared adding 8443

Comment: I'd +1 this, if there wasn't the recommendation to run as root in #4. There are multiple ways to make tomcat answer port 80, but running as root is the one recommendation that just *must not* be done *ever*. While I'm at it: It appears that "running as root" and "naming the app ROOT" have something to do with each other - but they absolutely don't. I'd recommend to make the ROOT webapp name a 5th point to separate it from running on port 80.